# PHP Query Result From One Column to Multiple Columns

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

```
// Database Settings 
define('DB_HOST', '******');
define('DB_PORT', '******');
define('DB_USER', '******');
define('DB_PASS', '******');
define('DB_NAME', '******');

// Connection to Database
$database = new MySQLi(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME, DB_PORT);

$sql = 'SELECT AManufactureBrand.brand, AManufactureModel.model, AManufactureEdition.edition'
        . ' FROM AManufactureModel'
        . ' INNER JOIN AManufactureBrand ON AManufactureModel.brand_id = AManufactureBrand.brand_id'
        . ' INNER JOIN AManufactureEdition ON AManufactureModel.model_id = AManufactureEdition.model_id'
        . ' WHERE AManufactureEdition.edition=\'345i\'';

$resultSet = $database->query($sql);

// Begin building some HTML output

$html = '<table border="0">
<tr>
<th>Editions</th>
</tr>';

while ($row = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())
{
$html .= '<tr><td>' . $row['brand'] . '</td></tr>';
$html .= '<tr><td>' . $row['model'] . '</td></tr>';
$html .= '<tr><td>' . $row['edition'] . '</td></tr>';
}

$html .= '</table>';

echo $html;
?>
```

For example this query calls up BMW 3Series 345i, I have two results from mysql printed
to a table on my website. The problem the two records print out on one column going down
onwards.

Currently I get a result like this on my webpage two mysql records printing vertical down one column.

---

I'm trying to make it go across like this and print multiple cars next to each-other horizontally across.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but I would suggest replacing this:

```
// Begin building some HTML output

$html = '<table border="0">
<tr>
<th>Editions</th>
</tr>';

while ($row = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())
{
$html .= '<tr><td>' . $row['brand'] . '</td></tr>';
$html .= '<tr><td>' . $row['model'] . '</td></tr>';
$html .= '<tr><td>' . $row['edition'] . '</td></tr>';
}

$html .= '</table>';
```

with this:

```
// Begin building some HTML output

$html = '<table border="0">
<tr>
<th>Brand</th>
<th>Model</th>
<th>Edition</th>
</tr>\n';

while ($row = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())
{
$html .= '<tr>';
$html .= '<td>' . htmlentities($row['brand']) . '</td>';
$html .= '<td>' . htmlentities($row['model']) . '</td>';
$html .= '<td>' . htmlentities($row['edition']) . '</td>';
$html .= '</tr>\n';
}

$html .= '</table>';
```

That will give you proper 3 column output.  If that's not what you wanted, then clarify your question.

Comment: Still not clear what you're trying to do... Sorry.  Hopefully you can work something out from this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I know there's gotta be a better way to do it with HTML but this should work:

```
$ths = $tds1 = $tds2 = $tds3 = '';

while ($row = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())
{
$ths .= '<td>Editions</td>';
$tds1 .= '<td>' . $row['brand'] . '</td>';
$tds2 .= '<td>' . $row['model'] . '</td>';
$tds3 .= '<td>' . $row['edition'] . '</td>';
}

$html = "<table border="0">
<tr>$ths</tr>
<tr>$tds1</tr>
<tr>$tds2</tr>
<tr>$tds3</tr>
</table>
";
```

You could also just have multiple tables in succession.